# Generate a fix sequence of strings with C#/Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to generate 500 chars in an easy way without doing:

```
String range = "0123456789101112131415...";
```

I want to have an exact string of 500 chars.

How can I do that?

`Enumerable.Range(0,500).Select( c => c.ToString());`

does not help because

the number 123 is 3 chars not 1 and therein is the problem.

Comment: Elisa your question and the accepted answer doesn't match. Why didn't you simply ask that you wanted *any* string with 500 chars in length?

Comment: @L.B sorry for the misunderstanding. My range sample should only be used as a sample but now I see u thought it literally... My bad :/

Comment: The question was clear to me "I want to generate 500 chars in an easy way"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't care which characters then you could just use the String constructor:

```
String s = new String('0', 500);
```

This will give you a string with 500 "0"s.  Or for 500 X's:

```
String s = new String('X', 500);
```

Comment: Easier it can not be. Thanks for this. I never thought of that hehe. I need to easily generate test data strings for my fluent validation unit tests ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx):

```
  string range = Enumerable.Range(0,500)
                .Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
  Console.WriteLine(range);
```

This will give you a string of concatenated numbers from 0 to 500. Like this: `01234567891011121314151617...`
if you need to take 500 chars from this big string, you can further use substring.

```
string range = Enumerable.Range(0,500)
              .Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
Console.WriteLine(range.Substring(0, 500));
```

Comment: i think the op wanted a string of length 500.check L.B's answer

Comment: @CodeIgnoto, my second example shows how to get string of 500. Maybe not as efficient as L.B's answer though

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
var range = new string(String.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 500)
                                               .Select(c => c.ToString()))
                             .Take(500).ToArray()
                      );
```

Comment: "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.String]" this is what I got fromt this.

Comment: @Kaf Try with a newer version of .Net

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is nifty, but you don't *always* need it...:

```
static string NumString(int length) {
    var s = "";
    var i = 0;
    while (s.Length < length) {
        s += i.ToString();
        i++;
    }
    return s.Substring(0, length);
}
```

Or a variant using Aggregate:

```
var str = Enumerable.Range(0, 500)
          .Aggregate("", (s, next) => s += next.ToString(), 
                         s => s.Substring(0, 500));
```

Comment: +1 for the opening statement. LINQ isn't always the best answer, but if you just need something quick and dirty with little care for performance it saves a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
new string(Enumerable.Range(0,500).SelectMany(x => x.ToString()).Take(500).ToArray())
```

Simplest way with LINQ. Since a string is technically an enumerable (char[]), you can use SelectMany (which takes multiple Enumerables and flattens into a single collection) followed by a Take(500) to only get 500 characters, call ToArray to get a char[] to instantiate a new string.

Answer (score 0):

One more option, not quite the requested output from the original question - digits are random rather than increasing - but fairly succinct (I know, the OP didn't require a string of *random* digits but here's one in any case).

```
var rand = new Random();
string.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat(0, 500).Select(i => rand.Next(10)));
```